# Letters in Mailboxes so that none are in the right one

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can 5 letters be put in 5 mailboxes such that none are placed in the right one ? I creatively thought labeling the letters & mailboxes 1-5 ,  it would be saying letter 1 can be placed in any of the other four . So a total of 4^5 ways .this was not one of the answers . Then i thought hmm lets write as an example 13254 as a sequence above 12345 ..this sequence is a ' throw-out ' case because the 1 cant go with the 1. This would generate _ _ a two digit number ..one for the letter and one for the mailbox .as an example 12 is legit . ( letter 1 in mailbox 2 ) while the pairs 11,22, ect are not .
This would give 5 possabilities for the first number and 5 for the second , or 5x5 =25. But then we must subtract out the posabilities of the 11, 22, 33, ect 
This gives 25- 5 =20 but that is STILL not one of the answers

Comment: Permutations in which no object is left in its proper place are called  [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: This is called $D_5,$ the number of derangements of $5$ things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are known as derangements.

Look here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: You all are derranged .

Comment: I dont see why my way that seemed so intuitively true was errored ?  btw merry x^3 mas fellow  math nerds 

Answer (score 2):

So you count bijective functions from $\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}$ to $\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}$ such that $f(i) \ne i$

I would do like this: Let $A_i$ be a set of functions with $f(i)=i$. Then

$|A_i|= 4!$ and

$|A_i\cap A_j|=3!$ and

$|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|=2!$ and

$|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k\cap A_n|=1$

You are interested in $|A_1'\cup A_2'...\cup A_5'|$. Let's use PIE

$$|A_1'\cup A_2'...\cup A_5'| = 5!-5\cdot 4!+{5\choose 2}3!-{5\choose 3}2!+ {5\choose 4}1!- {5\choose 5}\cdot 1=...$$

Comment: NB using the definition of factorial, we can rewrite the sum as $5! (\frac{1}{0!} - \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!} - \frac{1}{5!})$. Then using the power series for $\exp$ and a straightforward estimate shows that we can write this as $\left[\frac{5!}{e}\right]$ (here $[a]$ denotes the integer closest to $a$) and that this formula generalizes to when we replace $5$ with any positive integer.